# Create a Generalized Formula to Create Returns Projection

Tags: python, pandas, return, formula, projection

I have returns for 3 different portfolios for a period of 5 years. I want to build a formula that creates a projection for 10, 15 & 20 years. Assuming that history repeats its self every 5 years. So if return in first 5 years is 50% than for the upcoming 5 years the return would be 50% too.

```
+-------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|             | 5 years | 10 Years | 15 Years | 20 years |
+-------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| Portfolio 1 | 35%     | 82%      | 146%     | 232%     |
| Portfolio 2 | 40%     | 96%      | 174%     | 284%     |
| Portfolio 3 | 80%     | 224%     | 483%     | 950%     |
+-------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I've filled up the projection for 10, 15 & 20 years using formula as below:

```
nth_year_return = (((5yr_return +1)^nth_year)-1)/1
```

So for example in case of portfolio 1 10 years return would be calculated as below:

```
10th_year_return = (((35% +1)^2)-1)/1 = 82%
```

For 15 years return would be calculated as below:

```
15th_year_return = (((35% +1)^3)-1)/1 = 146%
```

For 20 years return would be calculated as below:

```
20th_year_return = (((35% +1)^4)-1)/1 = 232%
```

I am not quite confident with the formula that I've created. I want to verify if the used formula is correct or not? If not what is the error and how can I rectify that.

I've created a python function as below to calualate the projection.

```
def proj(5_yr_return, nth_year):
    val = (((5_yr_return + 1)**nth_year)-1))/1
    return val
```

Comment: your formula looks absolutely fine to me, and your function as well. Not sure the question is wholly appropriate for stackoverflow though as not really a coding question, probably better at https://quant.stackexchange.com/ (if you do not believe my answer that is :-))

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for this kind of question